# SQL Server 2012: Give rights to read ddl but not modify?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ddl

What rights would I need to be give a user for them to be able to view all DDL code (such as stored procedure code) but not be able to edit any of it?

The only possibility seems to be DDLadmin, but that would allow a user to edit as well.  Is there some other options, or perhaps a way to grant and then revoke part of DDLAdmin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give `VIEW DEFINITION` at the object, schema or database level.

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.objectname TO [user/role];

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::schemaname TO [user/role];

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::databasename TO [user/role];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173848.aspx